# sp_executesql with always true condition

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

i have been using dynamic queries in sql-server like:

```
declare @sql nvarchar (1000),@condition nvarchar(100)='';
set @sql=N'select * from tablename where (0=0)'+@condition+'';
exec(@sql)
```

by this i was able to get my result whether the @condition has any value or not.
But i got to know that `sp_executesql` is better then `exec` as it promote query plan reuse.

So, i tried my query with `sp_executesql,

```
set @sql =N'select * from dbo.testclient where (0=0) @condition'
exec sp_executesql @sql,N'@condition nvarchar(100)',@condition
```

but it failed with an error as

```
Incorrect syntax near '@condition'.
```

My problem is how can i make the above query to work with `sp_executesql` where the parameter @condition can be a condition or blank (' ') and what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Dynamic sql is risky. Perhaps you should try to figure out a way to get what you want without it.

Comment: This is still an open door to sql injection attacks. If the user enters in the condition `column='value';drop table tablename;--`, what do you think will happen?

Comment: @ZoharPeled first of all thanks for pointing that issue, we are pragmatically creating the parameters for the query and second i just wanted to avoid writing multiple condition to get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use variables such as @condition in sp_executesql, it does not simply replace your variable in the sql string with the content of the variable.

What happens is that the variable is bound to the supplied value and the sql statement is untouched.

This all means that you need to create a full sql statement which uses variables if you want to leverage query plan reuse.

For example:

```
SET @byIDsql = 'select * from tableName where (0=0) and Id = @Id'
SET @byNameSQL = 'select * from tableName where (0=0) and FirstName = @FirstName'
```

Then you can use sp_executesql to supply the value of @id and @firstName and get query plan reuse.

```
exec sp_executesql @byIDsql, N'@ID INT', 15
```

Comment: i was actually trying to avoid writing multiple queries.

Comment: Yea, it is a hassle. You can still generate the queries but it does require more work. Work is hard to get around if you want to stay safe from sql injection and/or want to maximize query plan reuse.

Comment: I strongly recommend reading this enormous blog post by Erland Sommarskog http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: Wrong link, but both are good. This is what you are trying to do  http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Answer (score 0):

Tested code,

```
     DECLARE @Sql   nvarchar(MAX)='',                                
        @paramlist  nvarchar(4000),          
 @id int=3
 set @paramlist = N' @id1 int'
set @Sql='select * from test where id=@id1'

exec sp_executesql @Sql,@paramlist,@id 
select @Sql
```

Comment: @PeterHenell , i gave the syntax of sp_executesql only without testing the execution plan.query plan may not be reuse for dofferent rason.Now check my script.

Comment: @PeterHenell , now check

Comment: Yep, thats the way to do it.

Comment: @PeterHenell , Thanks.Suppose this was not dynamic.even then declaring local variable is wise idea to avoid parameter sniffing.This was plan may be resuse.Am i thinking in right direction ?

Comment: sp_executesql will sniff the value 3 for parameter `@id1`, just like a regular procedure would.